# How to add profile_pic field from another model in one model

Tags: html, django, django-models

I want to add profile_pic in Blog View page which is in my Profile model

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile/")

class StudentBlogModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True,null=True)
    snippet = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

**Views.py**

```
class BlogView(ListView):
    model = StudentBlogModel
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = "StudentBlogModel_list"   
    paginate_by = 10
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
            <hr>
                <div class="profile-feed">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-start profile-feed-item">
                      <img src="{{ }}" alt="profile" class="img-sm rounded-circle mb-5 mx-2">
                      <div class="ml-4">
                        <h6>
                        {% if StudentBlogModel.author.first_name or StudentBlogModel.author.last_name%}
                            <small class="card-title">{{StudentBlogModel.author.first_name|capfirst}}
                            {{StudentBlogModel.author.last_name|capfirst}} </small>
                        {% else %}
                            <small class="card-title">{{StudentBlogModel.author.username|capfirst}}</small>
                        {% endif %}
                       <small class="ml-4 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-clock mr-1"></i> {{StudentBlogModel.post_date}}</small>
                        </h6>
                        <p>
                          {{StudentBlogModel.title}}
                        </p>
```

what to write in src to get profile pic of particular author

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if StudentBlogModel.author.profile.profile_pic %}
      <img src="{{StudentBlogModel.author.profile.profile_pic.url}}"alt="profile"class="img-sm rounded-circle mb-5 mx-2">
{% else %}
      <img src="{% static '..default-image' %}" alt="profile" class="img-sm rounded-circle mb-5 mx-2">
{% endif %}
```

You should try this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="{{ StudentBlogModel.author.profile_pic.url  }}" alt="profile" class="img-sm rounded-circle mb-5 mx-2">
```

And by the way, if you are trying to make a user profile I would suggest using a DetailView instead:

```
class BlogView(DetailView):
    model = StudentBlogModel
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = "StudentBlogModel_list"   
    paginate_by = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing pk in your views

```
def profile(request, pk):
    uprofile = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'accounts/users_profile.html', {'uprofile':uprofile})
```

this is my code for users profile when you want to see others profile, maybe it will help

and put this in your urls.py

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{ StudentBlogModel.author.profile_pic.url  }}" alt="profile" class="img-sm rounded-circle mb-5 mx-2">
```

If this not working have you added a profile pic to an author or creating a default picture for profile pic.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile/", default='default.jpg')
```

Add default.jpg in media folder and should be working.